# How to delete first line of a file from powershell ise?

Tags: powershell

I have a file with the content of

```
09-JAN-2018
12-FEB-2018
13-MAR-2018
```

Could you help me on, How could I delete the first line of the file from PowerShell.

Thank you in advance

Comment: 09-JAN-2018 is in one line 12-FEB-2018 in second line and 13-Mar-2018 is on third line

Answer (score 5):

This takes the data from file1.txt without the first line, then prints it into file2.txt

```
Get-Content file1.txt | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Out-File file2.txt
```

But it will be usefull to know if you are working with a .txt file, a .csv, .xml or other type of file.

Comment: Thank you, what will happen if the file has only one line. How could I remove it please

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
get-content $file |
    select -Skip 1 |
    set-content "$file-temp"
move "$file-temp" $file -Force
```

Comment: Thanks uni_x, and how could we delete if there is only one line into a file.

Comment: Remove-Item $pathToFile

Comment: Thanks again but remove-item will remove the file itself but I would like to delete first line of a file. Not the file itself

Comment: If you know it‘s a data with one line you could use `Set Content -Path $path -Value $null` (untested)

Comment: Thanks again Uni_x, but I don't have any transparency to know which file has only one line, i tried with your solution but it will not work if there is only one line in a file.

Comment: Here is a script which only delete the first line if the whole document has only one line: `$Path = "C:\test\1.txt"
$AllText = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($Path)`
`$Lines = $AllText.Split("`n")`
`"Number of Lines: {0}" -f $($Lines.Count) `


`if($Lines.Count -eq 1) {
Set-Content -Path C:\test\1.txt -Value $null
} `